# How can I append two dictionary in array?

Tags: swift

I want to make json data like the below.

```
{
 "key1":"value1",
 "key2":"value2",
 "key3":[{"key3_1":"value3_1","key3_2":"value3_2"}]
}
```

But my result is the following:

```
{
 "key1":"value1",
 "key2":"value2",
 "key3":[{{"key3_1":"value3_1"},{"key3_2":"value3_2"}]
}
```

my code implementation is the following:

```
let json: [String: Any] = [
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2",
            "key3" : ["key3_1":"value3_1", "key3_2":"value3_2"]
        ]
```

Seems that Problem is to add two dictionary into array[0]..
Is there anyone to help this problem?

Comment: "code implementation" that's not your implementation, that's your input. What are you doing with it, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
let json: [String: Any] = [
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2",
            "key3" : [["key3_1":"value3_1", "key3_2":"value3_2"]]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `NSJSONSerialization`? Just add a pair of square bracket to denote that `key3` is an array of dictionary and you will be fine:

```
let json: [String: Any] = [
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3" : [
        ["key3_1": "value3_1", "key3_2":"value3_2"]
    ]
]

let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
print(str)
```